# Interaction analysis when different groups are used for the between-subjects variable and the within-subjects variable?

Tags: mixed-model, repeated-measures, interaction

I would be very grateful if someone could help me out here.

I have three groups: I ask one group "Should you help A?", I ask the other group "Should you help B?" and I ask the third group both questions. Participants respond on a Likert scale to these questions.

So, I have a between-subjects variable (questions presented separately vs questions presented jointly) and in the case of the third group, a within-subjects variable (A vs B). How can I analyse an interaction in this case?